# Cant find output file from a program deployed from the ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that basically create a CSV file from a database. Below is the code that I use

```
public void ExportToCSV(string row, int rowNo)
{
  FileStream aFile;
  try
  {
    if (rowNo == 0)
      aFile = new FileStream(@"..\..\Check.txt", FileMode.Create);
    else
      aFile = new FileStream(@"..\..\Check.txt", FileMode.Append);

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
    sw.WriteLine(row);
    sw.Close();
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("An IO exception has been thrown!");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }

}
```

The code works ok if I run it from VS2010. The CSV file is created under the program folder. Now I want to be able to install this program to other PCs, so I use ClickOnce. Now with ClickOnce, what I don't understand is it seems that my program does not have its own folder but just a shortcut on my startmenu, but the program runs ok. The confusing thing is I cannot find where the output file is. In one of the XP station, I was able to find it using a search but it is inside some random folder but I cannot find it in Windows 7. Can anyone give me a suggestion what am I doing wrong? Or how I can change the program so it is easily deployed but I can still find where the file is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467687/clickonce-deployment-location.  You should not be writing to relative path from your program's install location.

Comment: Found the file here:
C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this problem is to have a preconfigured path in your app.config.
This path could be inside a well known folder described in the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum

At runtime you get the full path of your folder in this way

```
string myFolderName = Properties.Settings.Default.OutputFolder;
string documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string finalPath = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, myFolderName);

if (rowNo == 0) 
   aFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(finalPath, "Check.txt", FileMode.Create); 
else 
   aFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(finalPath, "Check.txt", , FileMode.Append);
```

See here for refs on [working with Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)